# Unexpected token ) failing to debug script

Tags: javascript, debugging

at the moment I am trying to debug this whole script! I cannot seem to get it to work.

At the moment when I run it I get this error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Does anybody know why? Where have I put brackets in the wrong place? Thanks!

```
var hats = [124472052, 67996263];
var request = 25;

        var Loop = setInterval(function(){
                for (var Id in hats) {
                        var origLink = "http://www.roblox.com/x-item?id=" + hats[Id];
                        $.get(origLink,function(data){
                                var Regex = /item\Dprivatesale\Dprice\D\D([\d])\D\Dspan\D/;
                                var PriceSelling = data.match(Regex)[1];
                                PriceSelling = Number(PriceSelling.replace(",",""));
                                if (PriceSelling <= request) {
                        var hatBuying = "http://m.roblox.com/items/" + hats[Id] + "/privatesales";
                        $.get(hatBuying, function(data){
                                        var Regex2 = /<a href="\/Catalog\/VerifyTransfer\\?userAssetOptionId=([\d,]+)\Damp;expectedPrice=([\d,]+)">/;
                                        var buyId = data.match(Regex2)[1];
                                        var buyLink = "http://m.roblox.com/Catalog/VerifyTransfer?userAssetOptionId=" + buyId + "&expectedPrice=" + PriceSelling;
                                        var Explorer = document.createElement('iframe');
                                        function Buy(){
                                                Explorer.contentDocument.forms[0].submit();
                                        };
                                        Explorer.onload = Buy;
                                        Explorer.width = "300";
                                        Explorer.height = "400";
                                        Explorer.src = buyLink;
                                        document.body.innerHTML = "";
                                        document.body.appendChild(Explorer);
                                        clearInterval(Loop);
                                }
                        });
                }
            });
        },0)
```

Comment: Run your code through http://jshint.com/

Comment: This is one reason we develop and test incrementally, btw.

Comment: Fixed script: http://jsfiddle.net/KPt8w/

Comment: dfsq - It says $ is undefined. What does that mean in this context?

Comment: I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object function bound(var_args)
    {
        return func.apply(thisObject, args.concat(slice(arguments)));
    } has no method 'get'

Answer (score 0):

In the line before last. It should be just `}`, not `})`.